# Auto calculate value including decimals

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html form where users add hours to 5 input fields (days of the week).

The total hours is then displayed at the bottom of the form.

This is working fine for rounded hours, but when adding something like 7.4 the total is rounding it to 7

See below:
Is there a way to add the decimals too?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.calc').change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.calc').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() != '') {
        total += parseInt($(this).val());
      }
    });
    $('#total').html(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control  calc" name='mon'>
<input type="text" class="form-control  calc" name='tue'>
<span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: use `parseFloat`

Comment: Where would this go?

Comment: Instead of `parseInt`

Comment: Java is not JavaScript

Comment: Thanks @MysterX - Thats worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MysterX pointed out, you are converting the user's input into integer(whole number) form. `parseFloat` will account for decimal places.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly. Just to add, is there a way to show this to just 2 decimal places?

Comment: Yes, to limit you'll want to do parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2);

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the number of decimals instead of a long and ugly float, change this line

```
total += parseInt($(this).val());
```

To this

```
total += parseFloat($(this).val());
```

And change this line

```
$('#total').html(total);
```

To this

```
$('#total').html(total.toFixed(2)); //If you want two decimals
```

Comment: the long and ugly float is only happening with multiplication and division.

Comment: @mplungjan but I don't think I should assume the numbers being received are all nice and truncated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `parseFloat` instead because `parseInt` will round off.

```
total += parseFloat($(this).val());
```

**[>>Sample Demo<<](https://jsfiddle.net/x4qjq1zk/1/)**

Comment: Please use `<>` snippet editor instead of JSFiddle so the answer stays here

Comment: Sure, we can do that